# How to iterate through a hidden column in jquery data table

Tags: datatable, datatables, jquery-plugins

I have a data table that has a hidden column. I want to set the values of that column to a java script array. (Note: I want to get the values that belong to the current page only). If I use a search filter, I want the values of the current page of the search result.

I've tried like this.

```
$('#datatbl').DataTable().rows({filter: 'applied'}).every(function () {
      var row = this.data();
      arr.push(row[0]);                    
});
```

But,this code gives all values from all the pages. Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding page:'current' in selector.

```
$('#datatbl').DataTable().rows({filter: 'applied', page:'current'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It was really helpful.